After resetting STM32, I get a serial connection error on python. How can i handle this in python?
I get a problem on my Python serial, after doing a jump from Application to the bootloader on my STM. On my python-side on Windows, I close the serial and open it again. Also, I reset the input and the output buffer before I start reading from the serial. The STM32 has already again started up and his serial connection is open. When I simply close and execute the python script again, there is no problem.
class serialHandler:
    delay = False
    ser= serial.Serial()
    ser.port = system.configComPort.COMPORT
    ser.baudrate = system.configComPort.BAUDRATE
    ser.parity = system.configComPort.PARITY 
    ser.open()
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super(serialHandler, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance
    def isDelay(self):
        return self.delay
    def setDelay(self):
        self.delay = True
    def resetDelay(self):
        self.delay = False
    def reopenSer(self):
        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
        self.ser.close()
        print("serial close")
        sleep(2.5)
        print("serial open")
        self.ser= serial.Serial()
        self.ser.port = system.configComPort.COMPORT
        self.ser.baudrate = system.configComPort.BAUDRATE
        self.ser.parity = system.configComPort.PARITY 
        self.ser.open()
        self.ser.reset_input_buffer()
        self.ser.reset_output_buffer()
    def readUnil(self):
        dataFrame = self.ser.read_until(expected = END_OF_USB_MSG.encode())
        return dataFrame
    def write(self, data):
        self.ser.write(data)
    def isOpen(self):

The error gets thrown when i do a readUnil()
Exception has occurred: SerialException
ClearCommError failed (PermissionError(13, 'Das Gerät erkennt den Befehl nicht.', None, 22))
  File "D:\projects\efas\code\command\serial_usb.py", line 195, in readUnil
    dataFrame = self.ser.read_until(expected = END_OF_USB_MSG.encode())
  File "D:\projects\efas\code\command\serial_usb.py", line 224, in run_readline_serial
    data_frame = serHandler.readUnil()
serial.serialutil.SerialException: ClearCommError failed (PermissionError(13, 'Das Gerät erkennt den Befehl nicht.', None, 22))

I guess after the reset of the STM32, on Windows the old comport is used which is no more existing. Is there a way of completely forget the old connection on the pyhton side and reestablish?

I would guess that the STM32 is resetting without waiting for all serial data to be sent.  Get rid of the call to .readUnil() that's causing the error, or at least put it inside a try.
